# I'm trying to extract data to develop a graph which shows certain results

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to produce a bar chart which will show 'Cancellations per Region per Quarter Cancelled amount'. When I try to use any code it will either come out showing the incorrect data or when selecting one of the columns will say that the data type is wrong as it is a Varchar rather than a number.
The columns I have are

```
DATE_OF_CANCELLATION (Date)
CUSTOMER (Varchar)
REGION/SVP (varchar)
AMOUNT_CANCELLED (This is a price)
ARR (This is a price)
TCV (This is a price)
DATE_OF_ENTRY (Date)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to show the above statement of 'Cancellations per Region per Quarter Cancelled amount'. The table name I am using is `Cancellations-FY22`

The Code I have used so far is

```sql
SELECT "AMOUNT_CANCELLED" FROM "CANCELLATIONS-FY22"
ORDER BY "REGION/SVP"
```

I have tried to `Select * FROM` the table but that shows all the data which I do not want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. Also, using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice (as you have to use them everywhere and have to always use the correct case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` the region and quarter and `COUNT` the cancellations:

```sql
SELECT "REGION/SVP",
       TRUNC(date_of_cancellation, 'Q') As quarter,
       COUNT(AMOUNT_CANCELLED) AS number_of_cancellations
FROM   "CANCELLATIONS-FY22"
GROUP BY "REGION/SVP", TRUNC(date_of_cancellation, 'Q')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, it brings up the regions I need then after those ones it becomes labelled as 'Group 8', 'Group 9' Etc. Is there anyway of changing this?

Comment: @Redders I have no idea because I cannot see your database or the data in your table so I cannot replicate the issue you are seeing.